# Understanding Time2Vec embedding for implementing this as a keras layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series

The paper time2vector [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.05321.pdf#section.4) (the relevant theory is in section 4) shows an approach to include a time embedding for features to improve model performance. I would like to give this a try. I found a implementation as keras layer which I changed a little bit. Basically it creates two matrices for one feature:

(1) linear = w * x + b

(2) periodic = sin(w * x + b)

Currently I choose this feature manually. Concerning the paper there are a few things i don't understand. The first thing is the term k as the number of sinusoids. The authors use up to 64 sinusoids. What does this mean? I have just 1 sinusoid at the moment, right? Secondly I'm about to put every feature I have through the sinus transformation for me dataset that would make 6 (sinusoids) periodic features. The authors use only one linear term. How should I choose the feature for the linear term? Unfortunately the code from the paper is not available anymore. Has anyone worked with time embeddings or even with this particularly approach?

Comment: It looks like what they're doing with sines is similar to a [fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition), 3Blue1Brown has a good [video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6sGWTCMz2k). From a glance at the paper (so I might be mistaken) it also looks like they run _only_ the time through the transformation so they get a bunch of extra features to encode for the time.

Comment: Yes, it seems mostly like a Fourier series, I already watched this video but it wasn't quite helpful in understanding what to do here. So, if they just use the time which would make totally sense how do they gain 64 sinusoids from this single feature? Are they transforming the same feature multiple times? Thanks for your reply

Comment: They're transforming a single value of 'the moment in time that something happened' into multiple features. As humans we already do this, 'now' can be split into time of the day, day of the week, day of the month, day of the year, year, etc.. It looks like they do this in a clever automated way that uses 64 different cycle lengths (1/day, 1/week, 1/month etc. are probably in there)

Answer (score 0):

For my limited understanding, the linear transformation of time is a fixed element of the produced embedding and the parameter K allows you to select how many different learned time representations you want to use in your model. So, the resulting embedding has a size of K+1 elements.